Type 'E' does not satisfy the constraint 'object'
This error is throwing after upgrade the node version to 20. In node version 16 it was work perfectly
error TS2345: Argument of type 'E' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial | Partial[]'.
Type 'E' is not assignable to type 'Partial[]'
node : v20.12.2
@mikro-orm/nestjs: ^5.0.0
@types/mongodb: ^3.6.3
mongodb: ^5.9.2
@mikro-orm/core: ^5.9.2
@mikro-orm/mongodb: ^5.9.2
export abstract class TenantService<E> extends BaseService<E> {
  context: Context;

  opts?: TenantServiceOptions;

  constructor(
    respository: EntityRepository<E>,
    context: Context,
    opts?: TenantServiceOptions
  ) {
    super(respository);

    this.context = context;

    this.opts = opts;
  }
}


Please post the full error message.
